# End to end test http requests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, casperjs, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

**What end-to-end testing JavaScript framework is best to test outgoing HTTP requests?**

I want to test HTTP request's payloads as well.

I am considering Nightwatch.js, but so far I couldn't figure out if Nightwatch.js allows testing the HTTP request and its payload.

(I am not using AngularJS on my website.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [**Puppeteer**](https://pptr.dev/) to test HTTP requests.

There is an entire [`request`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-request) class built-in for when a request is issued by a page:

- [`request.abort()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestaborterrorcode)
- [`request.continue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestcontinueoverrides)
- [`request.failure()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestfailure)
- [`request.frame()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestframe)
- [`request.headers()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestheaders)
- [`request.isNavigationRequest()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestisnavigationrequest)
- [`request.method()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestmethod)
- [`request.postData()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestpostdata)
- [`request.redirectChain()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestredirectchain)
- [`request.resourceType()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestresourcetype)
- [`request.respond()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestrespondresponse)
- [`request.response()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestresponse)
- [`request.url()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requesturl)

There is also a [`response`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-response) class for when/if the response is received by the page for the request:

- [`response.buffer()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsebuffer)
- [`response.fromCache()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsefromcache)
- [`response.fromServiceWorker()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsefromserviceworker)
- [`response.headers()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responseheaders)
- [`response.json()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsejson)
- [`response.ok()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responseok)
- [`response.request()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responserequest)
- [`response.securityDetails()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsesecuritydetails)
- [`response.status()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsestatus)
- [`response.text()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsetext)
- [`response.url()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responseurl)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to go with nightwatch.js but had hard time capturing the request using nightwatch-xhr module. 

I will try Puppeteer now, hoping that request.headers() would also return a request payload.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use request-promise lib and to be happy)